# CSV export with filtered columns

Tags: google-appsheet

I am working on an appsheet application.

I created a view to show

[ID],[Name],[Price],[Date],[Owner]

in a table.

I added an action with "Export csv from this view xxxxx" to export the view into a CSV.

But when i clicked on the action, i only want to show [Name],[Price],[Owner] in the csv, i dont want to see other columns.  and also,  i want to convert the value in Price columns to different format.

Is there a way to allow me to export the csv with filtered columns?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this by configuring or assigning a Slice to your Action, instead of pointing the Action to the View that you have created, use the Slice that contains your desired data columns.

Check out these resources for more information:

- [Slices: The Essentials](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10106592?hl=en&sjid=5224870128749234443-AP)
- [Export this view to a CSV file](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/11579391?hl=en&sjid=5224870128749234443-AP)
- [Export CSV of filtered rows](https://www.appsheet.com/templates/This-app-shows-how-to-filter-your-data-using-a-form-and-export-it-to-CSV?appGuidString=1561bf63-ff85-4158-87e4-d29f7cab2c67)

Hope this helps.